# Kate has no window borders, and thus no minimize, maximize, and close buttons

Tags: window-manager, kate, window-decorations

#### I usually use kate as my preferred text editor, however, whenever I open it there are no window borders, and thus no maximize, minimize, and close buttons.  How can I fix this?

I tried going thought the view menu, but was unable to find any settings to alter this.

Moreover, it seems to be stuck in "always on top mode" and thus I cannot view my panel to use right click to close or modify it.

Pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> produces no change.

There is a scroll bar, but it doesn't appear to be controlled by the window manager (kwin) as it is much wider than normal and has a mini preview of the entire document as its background.  I'd prefer not to override this feature if possible.

I have an almost default install of Linux Mint KDE 16 x64.

Related: [How do I exit full screen after enabling via the right click context menu of kwin (KDE)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115543/how-do-i-exit-full-screen-after-enabling-via-the-right-click-context-menu-of-kwi)

Comment: A temporal workaround: `Alt+RightClick` inside the window; that should give you a list of commands (Min/Max/Always on top...)

Comment: @aularon it does not :(

Comment: If your installation is new, is it the same for your ~/.kde folder ? I kept the same one from KDE 4.0 to KDE 4.11, and I solved MANY problems by finally erasing it.

Comment: @kursus I'm not sure I understand what you are asking;  I didn't migrate an old ~./kde  I think I actually changed a setting in kate to make it go full screen, but then never figured out how to undo it.

Comment: Ok that was pretty much my question. Be aware that the fullscreen shortcut in Kate is ctrl+maj+F and not F11 like many other KDE apps.

Comment: Sorry I meant ctrl+shift+F

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### This will happen if you:

- right click on the kate window border *or* it's entry in the task manager bar
- select 'more actions' -> 'Full screen'

or

- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>

#### I originally solved this by:

- removing `katerc` from `~/.kde/share/config`

#### This is best undone by:

- pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with gwenview.
After entering-exiting fullscreen mode all window features (minimize, maximize,resize,exit e.t.c) disappeared.
The solution was to remove ~/.config/org.kde.gwenviewrc.
Search for kate related files in ~/.config.

`find ~/.config -name "*kate*"
~/.config/katerc
~/.config/katevirc
~/.config/katepartrc`

Cleaning resource files may help:
`mv ~/.config/katerc ~/.config/katerc.bak`

Comment: I wonder what feature/bug causes this obnoxious behaviour.