# How do I exit full screen after enabling via the right click context menu of kwin (KDE)?

Tags: kde, window-manager, kde4, kwin, fullscreen

This is related to my other question: [Kate has no window borders, and thus no minimize, maximize, and close buttons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115443/kate-has-no-window-borders-and-thus-no-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons)

In KDE, after right-clickin on any window border, or it's entry in the task manager, I can select `More Actions` and then `Fullscreen`.

Once in this mode, normal window manager commands such as <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> and  <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f4</kbd> no longer work.  Moreover, the task bar and everything else remain permanently hidden until I quit the window via the `File` menu.

### How do I un-fullscreen a window managed by kwin?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to kursus's [help here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115443/kate-has-no-window-borders-and-thus-no-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons) I have a quick answer:

- just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>